# Extracting contact information from html

Tags: python, html, regex

I want to extract the contact numbers from a portion of html . and I used

```
import codecs 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
page = codecs.open('D:/Edureka/Sample Addresses!.html', 'r+') 
page1 =page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page1, 'html.parser')
soup.prettify()
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
     script.extract()  
text = soup.get_text() 
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines()) 
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  ")) 
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
contacts = re.findall("\d{3} \d{3}-\d{4}", text)
for j in contacts:
    print(j)
```

This is not giving me desired answer. If I use

```
contacts = re.findall("\d{3} \d{3}", text)
```

It's giving me first six digits. whenever I am giving `-\d{4}` it's not working. Please help. I need 10 digit contact numbers.

Sample of text

> Ivor DelgadoAp #310-1678 Ut Av.Santa Barbara MT 88317(689) 721-5145
>   Pascale PattonP.O. Box 399 4275 Amet StreetWest Allis NC 36734(676)
>   334-2174 Nasim StrongAp #630-3889 Nulla. StreetWatervliet Oklahoma
>   70863(437) 994-5270 Keaton UnderwoodAp #636-8082 Arcu
>   AvenueThiensville Maryland 19587(564) 908-6970 Keegan BlairAp
>     #761-2515 Egestas. Rd.Manitowoc TN 07528(577) 333-6244 Tamara Howe3415 Lobortis. AvenueRocky Mount WA 48580(655) 840-6139 '''

Comment: Sorry for the code format.

Comment: please post your code in nicely formatted form as this is python and indentation matters

Comment: How to edit question here?

Comment: Add 'beautifulsoup' to narrow the question.

Comment: you can see it under the tags

Comment: use formatting in your code

Comment: Done. Please help me getting contact numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not matching the braces, and your regex would search only for numbers like `111 222-3333`.
I think you can work your way with this

```
>>> text = "Keaton UnderwoodAp #636-8082 Arcu AvenueThiensville Maryland 19587(564) 908-6970 Keegan BlairAp #761-2515 Egestas. Rd.Manitowoc TN 07528(577) 333-6244 Tamara Howe3415 Lobortis. AvenueRocky Mount WA 48580(655) 840-6139"
>>> re.findall("\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}", text)
['(564) 908-6970', '(577) 333-6244', '(655) 840-6139']
```

Comment: Hey, Working.. Cool. Thanks. What was my error by the way?

Comment: That is not a slash _after_ d{3}, its a slash _before_ the preceding slash ;). It escapes the closing `)`, just as it does at the very start of the regex

Comment: ohh. :) . Thanks a lot.